# Is it worth submitting a paper to journal-first track of a conference?

Tags: paper-submission

Some of the prestigious conferences in Computer Science and Engineering have a "journal first" track. In that track they accept recent papers from selected journals. An example is https://2020.esec-fse.org/track/esecfse-2020-journal-first.

Other than offering an opportunity to attend such a conference, what are the other reasons one may submit a paper to such a track? I feel that since the paper is exactly same as what is  already published in a top tier journal, publishing the same work in another venue won't have much benefit. At best, one can have another item in his/her list of publications, though of actually the same piece of work as an earlier one.

I will appreciate if you could shed some light on if there are any other reasons/benefits from submitting to such "journal-first" tracks.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The link suggests that you are not publishing twice: "The journal-first manuscripts are published through the journals and will not be part of the ESEC/FSE 2020 proceedings.", so it likely wouldn't be another item in the list of publications.

Comment: Thank you @GoodDeeds for pointing it out -- much appreciated! I shall assume that other such conferences too will have a similar approach. Nonetheless, your pointer is useful.